# I have PTO but plan on resigning -- when do I give my 2 weeks' notice?

Tags: united-states, resignation

I have upcoming PTO, but I also planning on resigning at my current job. Here are my options:

1. Give notice before I go on PTO, so 1 of those 2 weeks' notice is vacation.
2. Give notice while I am on PTO.
3. Give notice after I go on PTO. This is obviously the "safest," but I don't want to delay me leaving my current employer if I can help it.

Are any of these options, particularly 1 and 2, considered "bad"? (Of course, my company can't really "stop me" from leaving for another company.)

For context: I'm not working on anything critical at my current job. It's a hybrid workplace and most people work remote.

Comment: Being on leave during your notice period is bad, because it defeats the purpose of a notice period to begin with. Some managers, in some situations, will find it annoying. Is there any particular reason why you must be on leave for the remaining two weeks? Can't you just work normally, and then take a two week break before your next job (I assume your leave will get paid out?)

Comment: If you don't actually *work* your notice period, then your employer would be perfectly correct to tell anyone who asked that you gave no notice at all (unless you come to an agreement with them or they decide to fire you).

Comment: In the United States, the laws governing PTO vary from state to state. If you want good advice, you'll have to tell us in which state this is in.

Comment: There's also the option to turn your "2 weeks notice" into a "3 weeks notice": state your intention to leave 2 weeks before your PTO starts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if you are remote and not critical, the idea of giving notice is so that your employer can arrange handover of tasks and begin the process of replacing you.

If you take your holidays as part of your notice period you're possibly going to be making it difficult to do hand-over.

You could take your holiday, then come back and hand in your notice or don't take the holidays and get the money in your final pay. Those would be the fairest ways to go about it.

Comment: In the US, many states do not require a company to payout unused vacation time.

Answer (score 0):

Read you contract. What exactly does it say about notice (required, recommended, courtesy, etc.) and about PTO payout on leaving?

Armed with this knowledge, you can simply ask you manager what they would prefer. The whole idea behind the two weeks notice is to arrange for an orderly transition or hand-over but in many cases this can be done easily within a few days and for the rest of the notice period, the employee is just a "lame duck".

Chances are they are fine with you taking a week of PTO and one week of notice. If not, you need to negotiate. What's your best line to take depends on how exactly your contract is worded.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of the US is "right to work", where there are no contracts. Employers aren't required to give notice and "two weeks notice" is just common courtesy. People get fired for handing in notice and have to leave the same day. I've handed in my notice, then required to work until the last minute of the last day, and only after the work day ended was allowed to clean out my desk.